# In PCA, what is the difference between computing the eigenvectors for $X^T X$ and for the covariance matrix?

Tags: pca

Why do we calculate eigenvectors based on $X^TX$ and other times based on the covariance matrix? (What's the difference?)

I have found resources online some of which computes the (eigenvector,eigenvalue) pairs based on $X^TX$, others based on the covariancematrix.

---

Example of $X^TX$:  (From my lectures)
[image]

Example of covariancematrix:
https://youtu.be/g-Hb26agBFg?t=1505

Answer (score 1):

Given that you have observed the $N$-dimensional row vectors $\mathbf{x}_1^T,\mathbf{x}_2^T,\dots,\mathbf{x}_M^T$, these row vectors can be stacked together to form the $M \times N$ matrix $\mathbf{X}$ such that
$$
\mathbf{X} = \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{x}_1^T \\ \mathbf{x}_2^T \\ \vdots \\ \mathbf{x}_M^T \end{bmatrix}
$$
Then, note that
$$
\mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{X} = \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{x}_1 & \mathbf{x}_2 & \cdots & \mathbf{x}_M \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{x}_1^T \\ \mathbf{x}_2^T \\ \vdots \\ \mathbf{x}_M^T \end{bmatrix} = \mathbf{x}_1 \mathbf{x}_1^T + \mathbf{x}_2 \mathbf{x}_2^T + \cdots + \mathbf{x}_M \mathbf{x}_M^T 
$$
Additionally, note that the sample mean of the observed vectors is
$$
\hat\mu = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^M \mathbf{x}_i
$$
and the sample covariance matrix is
$$
\hat\Sigma = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^M (\mathbf{x}_i - \hat\mu)(\mathbf{x}_i - \hat\mu)^T
$$
If we assume that $\hat\mu = 0$, then the sample covariance matrix becomes
$$
\hat\Sigma = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^M \mathbf{x}_i\mathbf{x}_i^T = \frac{1}{N} \mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}
$$
Therefore, computing the eigenvectors of $\frac{1}{N}\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}$ is equivalent to computing the eigenvectors of the sample covariance matrix as long as the sample mean $\hat\mu$ is 0. Note that the scaling factor $\frac{1}{N}$ is not really important, as you can obtain the same eigenvectors, but the eigenvalues would be scaled by $\frac{1}{N}$.

Comment: So if you first normalize your data (so $\mu = 0$) and then compute the covariancematrix ... then it's the same thing, right? Except for the $\frac{1}{N}$ scaling difference of the eigenvalues.

Comment: @SebastianNielsen yes it is the same thing up to the $\frac{1}{N}$ scaling factor. Instead of "normalize", I would say "center" my data.